# How to listen incoming tcp connection and listening the data in android?

Tags: android, tcp

I m getting a response when i send the request to device (HardWare) but not getting response while listening the tcp data

```
final Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {
            Socket listener;
            public void run() {
                try{
                    System.out.print("######## Thread Started######");

                    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5555);

                    String message = null;
                    while(true){

                        listener = serverSocket.accept();
                        BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(listener.getInputStream()));
                        message = inFromServer.readLine();
                        System.out.println("*** Received message inside connection Thread"+message);

                    }

                }catch(Throwable e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(r1, 1000);
```

Comment: are you sure that your client is using correct IP address to connect to?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko yes . Can you suggest some Async TCP and UDP library for Socket listener

Comment: I dont think that there is sense to use some library in this case.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko,Okay. i need some help for listening the server socket continuously.